# Image превышает размер ImageButton - не видно background. Как исправить?

Tags: android, eclipse, изображения

В android-приложении я программно создаю много ImageButton в LinearLayout. Фоном у них выступает рамка, которая должна обрамлять основную картинку ImageButton. Но так как эта картинка здоровая, то она целиком заполняет пространство, выделенное под ImageButton, и рамки(background) не видно. Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему? Мне на ум приходит только поместить каждую ImageButton во FrameLayout и потом поверх неё нарисовать рамку... Но это, думаю, сильно загромоздит приложение(ImageButton'ов может быть до 100 шт.).

Вот пример кода:

```
LinearLayout linLayout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
linLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
LayoutParams linLayoutParam1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
//Добавляю созданный layout в существующий с вертикальной ориентацией
linLayout.addView(linLayout1, linLayoutParam1);
LayoutParams lpView = new LayoutParams(180,  180);
lpView.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 20);
//Создаю ImageButton
imgbtn = new ImageButton(this);
//Выставляю изображение, превышающее размер 180х180
imgbtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.largeImg);
//в drawable/border обычный rectangle со скругленными углами, рамочка
imgbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
imgbtn.setOnTouchListener(this);
linLayout1.addView(imgbtn, lpView);
```

Comment: попробуй использовать хмл разметку, там все косяки сразу видно...

Answer (score 1):

как вариант выстави для imageButton методом setPaddings() внутренные отступы

Comment: Картинка-то двигается, но все равно перекрывает background...

Answer (score 0):

Думается мне, что можно поиграться со ScaleType

Comment: Мне как раз нужно оставить масштаб неизменным, просто чтоб рамка вокруг кнопки появилась. 
Я пробовал imgbtn.setAdjustViewBounds(true), картинки уменьшаются и рамка видна, но мне бы именно без изменения масштаба...